# Lucene - Update documents using LongPoint Field as Term in writer.updateDocuments()

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to update a document in my index using writer.update(Term t, Document doc) method.
Update is successful if I specify a TextField in Term, but fails when I supply a LongPoint in Term

A sample of my code:

```
package com.luceneserver.core;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field.Store;
import org.apache.lucene.document.LongPoint;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StoredField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.MatchAllDocsQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;

public class SampleDocUpdates {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(new RAMDirectory(), new IndexWriterConfig());
        IndexReader reader;
        IndexSearcher searcher;


        // first document in the index
        Document initialDoc = new Document();
        // adding a text field
        initialDoc.add(new TextField("foo_text", "abc", Store.YES));
        // adding a numeric field
        initialDoc.add(new LongPoint("foo_number", 1000));
        // adding stored field to display hits
        initialDoc.add(new StoredField("foo_number", 1000));


        writer.addDocument(initialDoc);


        // second document in index which should update the first one..
        Document newDoc = new Document();
        newDoc.add(new TextField("foo_text", "def", Store.YES));
        newDoc.add(new LongPoint("foo_number", 2000));
        newDoc.add(new StoredField("foo_number", 2000));


        // update doc with foo_text:abc with the newDoc instance.
        writer.updateDocument(new Term("foo_text", "abc"), newDoc);

        reader = DirectoryReader.open(writer);
        searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = searcher.search(new MatchAllDocsQuery(), 1000).scoreDocs;

        for (ScoreDoc scoreDoc : scoreDocs) {
            System.out.println(searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc).get("foo_text")+"\t"+searcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc).get("foo_number"));
            //'def  2000'
        }


    }

}
```

This code successfully updates the initial document with second document...
but if I use

> writer.updateDocument(new Term("foo_number", 1000), newDoc);

It fails... My requirement is to update documents by uniquely identifying the documents based on the LongPoint field..
The documentation (lucene 6.3.0) has only updateDocuments() with Terms as selection criteria and not a LongPoint field.
Is there any alternative way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

All that `updateDocument` does is delete documents that contain the term, and then add the new document. So, you can just use `deleteDocuments`, which you can pass a Query to instead, followed by `addDocument` to accomplish the same thing.

```
writer.deleteDocuments(LongPoint.newExactQuery("foo_number", 1000));
writer.addDocument(newDoc);
```

Comment: what about atomicity of the operation? with two statements it's possible to be left in the incomplete state so now error handling is on you :(

Comment: is there a way to update a doc by multiple terms? as in i have a composite primary key in the index

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be addressed in the nearest Lucene release (9.7.0 I guess). There were a pull request that added an updateDocuments(Query, Iterable) method to IndexWriter.